# Getting subdomains to work locally with Laravel

Tags: laravel, localhost, subdomain

I am having a hard time getting subdomains to work locally. I have Docker serving the application to port 8080, and I am able to see the Laravel welcome screen. I then have a simple route setup like this:

```
Route::domain('{name}.localhost:8087')->group(function () {
    return 'Hello World';acrylic dns
});
```

I am using Laravel's basic server, i.e. `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8087`

When I try and view the page, nothing happens. It just goes to the welcome screen. I have even tried adding 'test.localhost' to the /etc/hosts file. Couple questions:

1) Can you have the port in the host like I have it there (in the Laravel route)?

2) I have seem somewhat similar posts where the solution was to use acrylic dns (on windows). I am using a Mac. Is this something where I need an actual DNS server?

3) I am planning on using nginx, do I need a 'beefier' web server to accomplish this?

With the basic Laravel server I have tried hard coding test.localhost in the route, with and without the port. I'm sure I am goofing something up, just not sure where. I am on a Mac, and I am running Laravel 5.6. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Artisan serve, go to

/etc/hosts (or similar)

```
127.0.0.1   subdomain.localhost
```

And open in the browser

```
subdomain.localhost:8087
```

Answer (score 1):

1) No, the web server configuration will listen on the port.

```
// nginx
server {
    listen 8080;
    ...
}
```

2) You add the subdomains in your `/etc/hosts` file and create separate nginx configurations:

```
// /etc/hosts
subdomain1.foo.localhost    127.0.0.1
subdomain2.foo.localhost    127.0.0.1
subdomain3.foo.localhost    127.0.0.1

// nginx subdomain1.foo.localhost.conf
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name subdomain1.foo.localhost;
    ...
}

// nginx subdomain2.foo.localhost.conf
server {
    # set different port if needed
    # listen 8082
    listen 8080;
    server_name subdomain2.foo.localhost;
    ...
}

// nginx subdomain3.foo.localhost.conf
server {
    # set different port if needed
    # listen 8083
    listen 8080;
    server_name subdomain3.foo.localhost;
    ...
}
```

3) Nginx is a production ready web server, you may need load balancers and multiple instances of the web servers to scale out, but nginx will be more than sufficient.